# Efficient algorithm for finding repeating bit patterns?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, binary-search-tree, string-matching

My problem is that i have a dataset which consists of around seven thousand 512-bit strings and i am looking for the most efficient method to compare them with each other and identify repeated sequences of 30+ bits.

I have considered using brute force but i think it doesn't seem to be a proper solution.

There are many algorithms out there that perform string matching but i don't know which of them suits best to my problem

Comment: Try Knuth-Morris-Pratt.  Anything from Knuth has to be good.  I found it to be very efficient when I implemented it in C++: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Comment: I am operating only on bits (1s and 0s). Would it work efficiently as well?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a large collection of strings and want to find long substrings common to all of those strings, you might want to consider building a *[generalized suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_tree)* for all of the strings.  Once you have done so, you can find all substrings common to any subset of the strings by iterating over the tree with a depth-first search and looking for substrings that have the end markers for multiple different strings.

Since the size of a generalized suffix tree is O(N), where N is the total number of characters across all of the different substrings, and the suffix tree can be built in time O(N), the overall runtime for this operation should be O(N).

Hope this helps!